# Multiplying binomials to come up with $ y^8 - 256 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\ { (y^4 + 16) }{ (y^2 + 4) }{ (y + 2) }{ (y - 2) }$$

How do I multiply these to come up with $\ {y^8 - 256}$

Comment: Right to left may be easiest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $$(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2.$$ Start with the two last ones, $$\ { (y^4 + 16) }{ (y^2 + 4) }\underbrace{ \color{royalblue}{(y + 2)  (y - 2)} }=\ { (y^4 + 16) }{ \underbrace{(y^2 + 4)  \color{royalblue}{(y^2-4)}} }=\ldots$$

Comment: I figured it out.

Comment: @W.Zlacki I added some colors and braces to hopefully help you visualize it better.

Comment: @W.Zlacki You're welcome, glad this helped you! :-)

Answer (score 3):

$$(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$$

$$\ { (y^4 + 16) }{ (y^2 + 4) }\color{red}{{ (y + 2) }{ (y - 2)} }=(y^4+16)(y^2+4)\color{red}{(y^2-4)}$$
$$(y^4+16)\color{red}{(y^2+4){(y^2-4)}}=(y^4+16)\color{red}{(y^4-16)}$$
$$\color{red}{(y^4+16)(y^4-16)}={(y^8-256)}$$